# Resizing a UIView containing UIButtons makes those buttons lose perspective position

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview, autoresize

I got a UIView that contains an UIIMageView and several buttons that are allocated on certain position related to the image of the UIIMageView.

The frame of the UIView is (0,0,250,250)
the UIIMageView that is within the UIView is set to autorisizing (all) in IB.
All buttons are set to autoresize (none) and origin middle.

When i change the frame of the UIView i.e (0,0,500,500) the UIIMageView (and image) resize OK but the buttons lose their perspective position by a few pixels (about 2 to 3 in the vertical and horizontal axis).

Is this normal? can someone advise?

Comment: paste your code, it helps to find problem

Comment: There's not much of a code here to be honest. It's as simple as described. The xib is 250x250 and depending on what I do with the view it goes to 500x500 using view.frame = (0,0,500,500); nothing fancy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no answer after all.
I must accept the fact that the resized view and the buttons within it will lose perspective position by 2/ 3 pixels off the x/y axis...

strange....

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the buttons inside another UIView and then setting the autoresizing options on this new view. You should leave the buttons without autoresizing inside the new view.

Comment: Any reason why I should be doing this?